# $3\times 3$ real matrix similar to a specific matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a $3\times 3$ real matrix $A$ with one real eigenvalue $\lambda$ and two complex ones. Is it true that there is a real matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is of the form $\begin{pmatrix}\lambda & 0 & 0\\ 0 & a & -b\\ 0 &b &a\end{pmatrix}$?

If this is true, how can I prove it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda, a+bi, a-bi$
then there exist a $P$ such that

$A = P\begin{bmatrix} \lambda\\&a+bi\\&&a-bi\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}$

$\begin{bmatrix} \lambda\\&a &b\\&-b&a\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}1&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}i\\&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}i&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \lambda\\&a+bi\\&&a-bi\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1\\&\frac 1{\sqrt2}&-\frac 1{\sqrt2}i\\&-\frac 1{\sqrt2}i&\frac1{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}$

$A = P\begin{bmatrix} 1\\&\frac 1{\sqrt2}&-\frac 1{\sqrt2}i\\&-\frac 1{\sqrt2}i&\frac1{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \lambda\\&a &b\\&-b&a\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1\\&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}1&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}i\\&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}i&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}1\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}$